# Compare timestamp to date

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I need to compare a timestamp to a date. I would just like to compare the date portion without the time bit. I need to check whether a timestamp occurs on the day before yesterday i.e. today - 2.

Could you show me a snippet please? Thank you.

I've been reading through the PHP docs but couldn't find a very clean way of doing this. What I found was converting the timestamp to a date with a particular format and comparing it to a date which I get by doing a time delta to get the date before yesterday and converting it to a particular format. Messy.

Comment: have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php

Comment: using mysql it would be like : where DATEDIFF(createdOn,'2010-11-2') = 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can arcieve  this by using the function [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

To round to a day I personaly like to edit the timestamp. This is a notations of seconds since epoch. One day is 86400 seconds, so if you do the following caculation:

```
$time = $time - ( $time  % 86400 );
```

You can convert it back to a date again with the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function of PHP, for example:

```
$readableFormat = date( 'd-m-Y', $time );
```

There is also much on the [internet](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql) about this topic.

Comment: nice suggestion thinking outside the box!  is there a chance this would ever round _up_ to the _next day_??

Answer (score 2):

you can use the strtotime function

```
<?php

$time = strtotime("5 june 2010");
$before = strtotime("-1 day",$time);
$after = strtotime("+1 day",$time);
```